# Xcode5 Code Coverage (from cmd-line for CI builds)

Tags: objective-c, code-coverage, xcode5, lcov

How can I generate code coverage with Xcode 5 and iOS7?

Prior to upgrading I was getting code coverage just fine. Now I can't see any *.gcda files being produced.

The cmd-line that I'm using is:

```
xcodebuild -workspace ${module.name}.xcworkspace test -scheme ${module.name} -destination OS=${module.sdk.version},name=iPad -configuration Debug
```

**Works with AppCode**

- When I execute the tests via AppCode I can see *.gcda files being produced in ~/Library/Caches/appCode20/DerivedData. . . I need this to work for my Continuous Integration builds.

**Works from Xcode IDE**

- Also works from Xcode IDE. . . is there a cmd-line that will produce coverage, or is this an Xcode bug?

Comment: this used to work fine with Xcode5-DP3 but got broken in more recent versions. i suspect that it's a bug, or might need some other additional (undocumented) flag to xcodebuild

Comment: I've logged a radar ticket. Will update here when I get a response.

Comment: Stucked with the same thing 2 days ago after installing Xcode 5 GM. Also I've updated app target to ios7, so there is no way to use trick with older simulators to generate reports.

Comment: @velkopopovizky Do you mean the deployment target? You only need to set the deployment target down, you can still up the SDK. . (I assume you already meant this, but just making sure).

Comment: Radar ID is: 14816067

Comment: Customer decided to support ios7 and above, so we temporary switched deployment target to ios7, but I think I'll kill myself in this case.

Comment: @JasperBlues 
I'm using ocunit2junit.

And I've changed the invocation method from:
_xcodebuild -workspace WORKSPACE_NAME.xcworkspace -scheme LogicTests -sdk iphonesimulator7.0 build | ./ocunit2junit_

to:
**xcodebuild -workspace WORKSPACE_NAME.xcworkspace -scheme LogicTests -sdk iphonesimulator7.0 test | ./ocunit2junit**

so, problem was - xcode 5 can't generate test reports via "build" build action. need to specify build action as "test"

Comment: @velkopopovizky I *am* specifying the build action as test. In my case they're "application" tests. . . so it works for you with logic tests?

Comment: @JasperBlues yes, I have separate target and scheme "LogicTests" with key TestAfterBuild=YES. BTW, "LogicTests" is not launching the app itself.

Comment: It actually doesn't work for me from Xcode - I can generate coverage for my test files but not for the files I test, which are in a static library.

Comment: @Sulthan - I believe my Typhoon project (Github) is set up to test via a static library, and has coverage. . Using the workaround below, I think.

Comment: @JasperBlues Well, it worked for me on iOS 6 but I would like to have a solution not a workaround.

Comment: With Xcode5 and running application tests I can't generate the .gcda files. What do I need to set in project settings or any where else to generate them ?

Comment: @IphoneDeveloper - To enable coverage in Xcode5 its the same as Xcode4. In a targets 'Build Settings' set 'Generate Test Coverage Files=YES', 'Instrument Program Flow=YES'. Once enabled you can proceed to the step that Sulthan outlined, so that .gcda files are properly flushed during testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update: New accepted answer**

In some cases the coverage flushing needs to be done from within the app itself. The solution's outline [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19136767/generate-gcda-files-with-xcode5-ios7-simulator-and-xctest) provide details.

Answer (score 15):

The following is a fix for `SenTestKit` - simply add this class to your Tests target. Something similar should be possible to do with `XCTest`

```
@interface VATestObserver : SenTestLog

@end

static id mainSuite = nil;

@implementation VATestObserver

+ (void)initialize {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"VATestObserver" forKey:SenTestObserverClassKey];

    [super initialize];
}

+ (void)testSuiteDidStart:(NSNotification*)notification {
    [super testSuiteDidStart:notification];

    SenTestSuiteRun* suite = notification.object;

    if (mainSuite == nil) {
        mainSuite = suite;
    }
}

+ (void)testSuiteDidStop:(NSNotification*)notification {
    [super testSuiteDidStop:notification];

    SenTestSuiteRun* suite = notification.object;

    if (mainSuite == suite) {
        UIApplication* application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        [application.delegate applicationWillTerminate:application];
    }
}
```

and add

```
extern void __gcov_flush(void);

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication*)application {
    __gcov_flush();
}
```

Why is this working?

Tests and the tested application are compiled separately. Tests are actually injected into the running application, so the `__gcov_flush()` must be called inside the application not inside the tests.

The little magic with the observer only enables us to check when the tests are going to end and we trigger `__gcov_flush()` to be called inside the app.

Comment: I'm trying to verify this as an accepted answer, however it seems the cmd-line for tests has stopped working in the GM release! Tried: xcodebuild -workspace ${module.name}.xcworkspace test -scheme ${module.name} -destination OS=7.0,name=iPad -destination-timeout=10 -configuration Debug . . will accept as soon as I can figure out how to run my test target through my build script.

Comment: It turns out that this also **fixes** AppCode. . when running via iOS7 simulator in AppCode, the usually lovely Test Reporter shows no results (only evidence of running tests is log statements). . however, adding this fix, also fixes the test report. . . unfortunately, however the test name appears twice. . still, nice work!

Comment: @JasperBlues I modified my answer a bit, maybe it will be better for you now.

Comment: Just tried calling __gcov_flush() from +testSuiteDidStop: without -applicationWillTerminate:. It worked for unit tests.

Comment: is __gcov_flush defined in some library or header ? I get link errors for this

Comment: That happens if you are compiling without code coverage enabled.

Comment: I've tried implementing this solution for XCTest, but get duplicate symbol error. I've added my own question to the site as this is already solved. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19136767/generate-gcda-files-with-xcode5-ios7-simulator-and-xctest

Comment: @Sulthan - Would you like to add an answer also here? Same solution I think but deals with gcovr : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112782/code-coverage-with-gcovr-and-xcode-5-is-not-working/19730601#19730601

Comment: @JasperBlues I am not using gcovr. I have my own bash script to convert gcda to cobertura. Gcovr probably returns zero because there are no files generated, that's all.

Comment: @Sulthan, not using gcovr either. But from what I can see the it also converts .gcda files to a report, so on iOS7 there'd be the same problem of it not flushing, hence no data files. I figured someone should answer that question or close it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

(This is not **the** answer, but a work-around . . .I'm still very much interested in a better solution)

**Use iOS 6.1 Simulator**

If you're targeting iOS 6.1 or earlier as a deployment target, you can use the 6.1 simulator.

- Install the iOS6.1 Simulator via preferences/downloads
- Use the following cmd-line:

  xcodebuild -workspace ${module.name}.xcworkspace test -scheme ${module.name} -destination OS=6.1,name=iPad -configuration Debug

Answer (score 1):

We found that we had to add a bit of code to get the gcda files to flush from the system.

Code addition is to add 
`extern void __gcov_flush();` to the top of your file and then call `__gcov_flush();` just before the entire test suite exits.

Full explanation is here: http://www.bubblefoundry.com/blog/2013/09/generating-ios-code-coverage-reports/

Answer (score 1):

With the information from here I was able to craft this version which is the least invasive I could think of. Just add to your unit tests and run the tests as normal. The ZZZ ensures it is the last run suite of tests.

I had to ensure I added the GCC_GENERATE_TEST_COVERAGE_FILES and GCC_GENERATE_TEST_COVERAGE_FILES compiler flags to my test unit target too to get the coverage out.

```
//
//  Created by Michael May
//

#import <SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h>

@interface ZZZCodeCoverageFixForUnitTests : SenTestCase

@end

@implementation ZZZCodeCoverageFixForUnitTests

// This must run last

extern void __gcov_flush();

-(void)testThatIsntReallyATest
{
    NSLog(@"FLUSHING GCOV FILES");

    __gcov_flush();
}


@end
```

**Edit, or another approach by Jasper:**

I stripped the VATestObserver from the other answer down to this:

```
@interface VATestObserver : SenTestLog
@end

@implementation VATestObserver

extern void __gcov_flush(void);

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication*)application
{
   __gcov_flush();
  [super applicationWillTerminate:application];
}

@end
```

Comment: I stripped the VATestObserver from @Sulthan's excellent answer down too. . . otherwise it was causing some issues with the AppCode test reporter. . . Hope you don't mind, I've edited you answer to include that approach too.

Answer (score 0):

Some more documentation here:

https://code.google.com/p/coverstory/wiki/UsingCoverstory

and some source code to use:

https://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FUnitTesting

You need GTMCodeCoverageApp.h/.m and GTMCodeCoverageTestsXC.h/.m or GTMCodeCoverageTestsST.h/.m depending on if you are using XCTest or SenTest.