# Generating gcda files to view the code-coverage from XCTests in IOS with Jenkins

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, continuous-integration, code-coverage

I want to view the code coverage by running gcovr on  generated gcda files. Jenkins seems to put the generated gcda files in Users/../Library/developer/Xcode/DerivedData/../../../i386. I expect them to be in Users/Shared/Jenkins/workspace/../build/example.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/example.build/Objects-normal/i386

When i run my IOS project with XCode locally it does generate gcda files and i can view my coverage.
Im running xcode 5 and all tests are created with XCTest.

I've set 'Generate Test Coverage Files=YES' and 'Instrument Program Flow=YES' for debug and release, basicly i have done everything according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19136767/generate-gcda-files-with-xcode5-ios7-simulator-and-xctest?lq=1)

In Jenkins i use the xcode plugin to build. It has two build commands. The first one builds with the target "example" and configuration debug. 
The second Xcode build command builds with the target "ExampleTests", configuration debug, arguments" test -destination OS=7.0,name=”iPhone Retina (4-inch)” and a scheme . In the output i can see the test being run and the simulator starts on the building machnine.

It seems i have missed something maybe in the project setting or havent set something right in the jenkins job. Maybe something like TEST_AFTER_BUILD=YES only then for XCode5.

Comment: I am in the same situation. When I run the test build step on my build machine, I can't find any .gcda files. But I can find them on my machine. I think the files are being generated in the derived data folder rather than Jenkins' workspace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you recognised the .gcda files are put in the "wrong" directory.

Do the following:

1. Select your application target in your Xcode-Project and go to "Editor -> Add Build Phase -> Add Run Script Build Phase"
2. Paste this script into the script field:

   ```
   echo "Creating derivedDataDirectory file"
   echo "${OBJECT_FILE_DIR_normal}/${CURRENT_ARCH}" > ${PROJECT_DIR}/derivedDataDirectory
   ```

   [XCode setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zgv7z.png)

   (This creates a file with the path to the derivedDataDirectory)
3. Go to your jenkins project, click on "Add build step" and select "Execute shell".
4. Paste this script into the "Command" field:

   ```
   #CopyCodeCoverageFile
   echo "Start copying code coverage Files"

   projectname="[YOUR PROJECTNAME]"

   source=$(cat ${WORKSPACE}/$projectname/derivedDataDirectory)

   cp -a $source/. ${WORKSPACE}/$projectname/


   #CodeCoverage
   echo "Start CodeCoverage"

   cd ${WORKSPACE}/$projectname

   [YOUR PATH TO GCOVR]/gcovr -r /private/tmp/workspace/${JOB_NAME}/$projectname --xml > ${WORKSPACE}/$projectname/test-reports/coverage.xml
   ```

   Insert [YOUR PROJECTNAME] and [YOUR PATH TO GCOVR]. If your PROJECTNAME or target has 
   spaces in it, this will cause trouble! Make sure all the paths are correct!
5. This works for me and if all your paths are correct it should work for you to.
   Im running XCTests on Jenkins using XCode 5. This should be the same as your setup.
   If you dont use gcovr to generate code coverage for cobertura you can delete the last step 
   in the script. If you are experiencing problems with gvovr try using gcovr 3.0 instead of 
   3.1!

Tell me if something is not working for you or you found a better solution!

Comment: it has a been while since i posted the question and At the moment i am not in the position to test it. The logic is clear and i will take your word for it ;)