# Xcode 5 double log for unit tests

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing

I have problem with running my unit test in Xcode 5.0. 
In logs every message is doubled, but checking with breakpoint show that every test runs once.

```
Test Suite 'Multiple Selected Tests' started at 2013-11-06 07:56:23 +0000
Test Suite 'Multiple Selected Tests' started at 2013-11-06 07:56:23 +0000
Test Suite 'ProjectTests.xctest' started at 2013-11-06 07:56:23 +0000
Test Suite 'ProjectTests.xctest' started at 2013-11-06 07:56:23 +0000
Test Suite 'ColorResourcesTests' started at 2013-11-06 07:56:23 +0000
Test Suite 'ColorResourcesTests' started at 2013-11-06 07:56:23 +0000
Test Case '-[ColorResourcesTests test_createDarkGrayColor_Should_ReturnDarkGray]' started.
Test Case '-[ColorResourcesTests test_createDarkGrayColor_Should_ReturnGray]' started.
Test Case '-[ColorResourcesTests test_createDarkGrayColor_Should_ReturnGray]' passed (0.000 seconds).
```

Test Case '-[ColorResourcesTests test_createDarkGrayColor_Should_ReturnGray]' passed (0.000 seconds).

Comment: XCTests are pretty buggy atm. Try restarting Xcode and run the tests again.

Comment: Already restarted multiple times, also checked that on multiple Macs. It is not big issue but it break my Jenkins build...

Comment: What happens if you only run one test? If it still doesn't work you should probably file a bug.

Comment: I was using code coverage fix from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19136767/generate-gcda-files-with-xcode5-ios7-simulator-and-xctest, problem was with ** XCTestLog** in user defaults

Comment: Cool, add that as an answer to your question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using code coverage fix from this question stackoverflow.com/questions/19136767/…, problem was with  **XCTestLogin** user defaults. ([Generate gcda-files with Xcode5, iOS7 simulator and XCTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19136767/generate-gcda-files-with-xcode5-ios7-simulator-and-xctest))

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    + (void)initialize {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"XCTestLog,GcovTestObserver"
                                                 forKey:@"XCTestObserverClass"];
    }
#endif
```