# Xcode 6 Code Coverage, no GDCA files "cannot open: No such file or directory"

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest

I am trying to generate GDCA files using gcov in XCode, and have been using [BubbleFoundry](http://www.bubblefoundry.com/blog/2013/11/code-coverage-revisited/) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19136767/generate-gcda-files-with-xcode5-ios7-simulator-and-xctest) as guides.

I have a separate test target created, which prints a bunch of lines when done like:

```
profiling: /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
  MyProject-HASH/Build/Intermediates/MyProject.build/Debug-iphoneos/
  MyProject Tests.build/Objects-normal/
  armv7/mysource.gcda: cannot open: No such file or directory
```

After trying the instructions in both posts I tried [setting up CoverStory](https://code.google.com/p/coverstory/wiki/UsingCoverstory), which resulted in the same error message.

My permissions in that directory:

```
   8 -rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      474 Nov  5 21:54 mysource.d
   8 -rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff      220 Nov  5 21:54 mysource.dia
 144 -rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff    71136 Nov  5 21:54 mysource.gcno
 296 -rwxrwxr-x    1 me  staff   148752 Nov  5 21:54 mysource.o
```

I previously tried running the permissions script from BubbleFoundy, but I still get the cannot open error (a.k.a. gdca files not written).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I was generating GCDA files to the phone, which weren't being found. I fixed this by manual deleting all the directories in `/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-HASH/Build/Intermediates/MyProject.build/` and then rerunning tests in the simulator.

Comment: Does that mean if your app does not support simulator then you can not access GCDA files?