# Test Coverage via command line Xcode 5.1

Tags: xcode, testing, code-coverage, ios7.1, xcode5.1

I have unit tests in xcode 5.1, ios7.1, when I run them via the test command within xcode I can see gcda and gcdo files generated in the appropriate place. When I invoke the test command via the command line I only get gcdo files. It must be something to do with the `__gcov_flush` method that needs to be called to generate the files (I put logs in the flush method I see it in the gui logs but not the terminal logs). I used help from these SO questions

- [Code coverage from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394655/xcode5-code-coverage-from-cmd-line-for-ci-builds)
- Followed basically all of this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19136767/generate-gcda-files-with-xcode5-ios7-simulator-and-xctest)

I have also followed the usual advice and set

```
Generate Test Coverage Files: YES
Instrument Program Flow: YES
```

At a project level.

My command:

```
xcodebuild -workspace "$WORKSPACE" -scheme "$SCHEME" -configuration Debug -sdk $IPHONESIMULATOR_VERSION ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES  clean build test
```

Is there a reason why it would work within xcode but not via the command line?